# How should I annotate a function returning a ctypes array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, annotations, definition

Consider the following Python code:

```
def foo(aqs : typing.List[int]) -> ??? :
    array_type = ctypes.c_int64 * len(aqs)
    ans = array_type(*aqs)
    return ans
```

What's the correct annotation for the return value of this function? (In place of `???`)

Comment: You should probably specify you mean a `ctypes` array

Comment: what is '*ids'?

Comment: @JörgBeyer, that was a copy-paste error: in place of `ids` I meant `aqs`

Comment: and "List", is that "ctypes.List"? i.e. not a type of "list" with a lower letter "L"?

Comment: @JörgBeyer, no, it's `typing.List`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function doesn't have a consistent return type, since the length of the returned array is part of the array's type. However, the type is always a subclass of [`ctypes.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Array), which is the most specific annotation you can use:

```
def foo(aqs: List[int]) -> ctypes.Array:
    ...
```

Comment: I suppose it's similar to a variable-length tuple: `Tuple[int, ...]`

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Python, but it seems that `typing.List[T]` is what you're looking for (like @JörgBeyer said in its comment, above).

Example of a function that returns a List of instances of class `RegistrationRequest` :

```py
import string
import typing
from datetime import datetime

from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass()
class RegistrationRequest:
    activity: string
    start_at: datetime


def registrations_requests() -> typing.List[RegistrationRequest]:
    return [
        RegistrationRequest('Zumba', datetime(2019, 6, 25, 12, 30, 0, 0)),
        RegistrationRequest('Zumba', datetime(2019, 6, 27, 19, 15, 0, 0)),
    ]


print('{0}'.format(registrations_requests()))
```

Output is:

```
[RegistrationRequest(activity='Zumba', start_at=datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 25, 12, 30)), RegistrationRequest(activity='Zumba', start_at=datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 27, 19, 15))]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use python's built in List type List[T]

```
def foo(aqs : typing.List[int]) -> List[T]:
array_type = ctypes.c_int64 * len(aqs)
ans = array_type(*aqs)
return ans
```

Replace T with the list type

Comment: A ctypes array is not a list.